# Can I enter the UK visa-free after being refused a visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, visa-free-entry

I had flown to the UK, without problems, in October 2016, to stay for a month with the person I am dating. I left and I tried to enter on November 30th. I was refused at the border for having a one-way ticket, and for carrying hairstylist shears in my suitcase. Border control thought that I was seeking employment in the UK, and said that they weren't satisfied that I had any ties to the US. This is both false and ridiculous.

I returned in December and, this time, I brought with me a ton of documents supporting the reasons I was there, where I was staying, financial support, etc., and they let me in. I was in the UK from December to the end of January 2017. When I got home, I thought it would be a better idea to apply for a visitors visa, so I applied and I just heard back today that I was refused.

Can I travel to the UK with supporting documents after being refused a visa? What are my options?

I'm so scared to be refused again, I just want to be in the UK to be with the person I love. [image]

Comment: Your refusal notice will contain most of the information needed to get you a quality answer, please scan, redact, and upload: (see this link for how) http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image/4090#4090  into your question thanks.  Without it, we will most likely mark your post as 'unclear'.

Comment: It seems as though over 4 months (Oct 2016 to Jan 2017) you spent more time in the UK than out of it. It probably looks to them as though your ties to the US are tenuous - particularly considering your SO is in the UK ...

Comment: Hello Kate, welcome to Travel.SE. The suspicion of the UK officials seems to be extremely reasonable. You are trying to spend about half of your time in the UK and another half in the US. That's immigration, and you should go that route if you want to do it properly. Ask on Expatriates.SE.

Comment: It honestly sounds like you're trying to live in the UK, which you **cannot** do as a visitor. Since you're spending roughly half of your time in the UK (if not more), you'll probably want to apply for a visa to join a partner in the UK. Not an expert on These visas, but AFAIK you want a "family of a settled Person" visa

Comment: Most people who have strong ties to their home country can't spend two months abroad in a four-month period. We can't be sure without seeing the refusal notice but, presumably, you failed to convince the UK that you'd leave at the end of your stated visit. Attempting to enter visa-free would be very risky: the refusal will be on your record and, look, you've just been told you can't come to the UK. What do you honestly think the result will be if you ask the same question again straight away?

Comment: What basis do you have for calling it "false" that the border force were not satisfied that you had ties to the US? Do you have any evidence that they were, in fact, satisfied of that? If they were, why would they lie about that?

Comment: I call it false and ridiculous because I have family in the US which I am extremely close with, I hold two jobs in the US, I own a car in the US and I'm a 7th generation who was born here. How would I not have ties to my home country. That's ridiculous. All I want to do is spend time with the person that i love who lives in the UK. I don't see how I am a flagged person for having honest intentions and for just wanting to visit to spend time with them. I don't want to move there, I just want to visit.

Comment: @Kate in order to help you we must see the refusal. Please follow Gayot's comment on how to do that.